# Jetty : 404 page shown when starting webapp

Tags: java, spring, jetty

I am trying to run our Spring-MVC based application with Jetty as the application container. Unfortunately, when I start the application, I get a 404 page. What am I doing wrong? Jetty version : 9.4 :

Screenshot :

[image]

Log :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -DSTOP.PORT=0 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -DOPTIONS=jmx -Didea.launcher.port=7537 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/akshay/Downloads/idea136/bin -Dspring.security.strategy=MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath start.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/tools.jar:/home/akshay/Downloads/idea136/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main --module=jmx,slf4j-log4j,session-store-gcloud /tmp/context7601552538379376293config/jetty-contexts.xml
Detected server http port: 8080
[2017-09-13 04:27:32,863] Artifact webappname:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
2017-09-13 16:27:33.429:INFO::main: Logging initialized @124ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2017-09-13 16:27:33.646:WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance of Jetty is not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this is not recommended.  See documentation at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
2017-09-13 16:27:33.773:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.6.v20170531
2017-09-13 16:27:33.797:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///home/akshay/Downloads/jetty-distribution-9.4.6.v20170531/webapps/] at interval 1
2017-09-13 16:27:33.800:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///tmp/context4442083180054405388deploy/] at interval 1
2017-09-13 16:27:33.815:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2017-09-13 16:27:33.815:INFO:oejs.session:main: Scavenging every 600000ms
2017-09-13 16:27:33.884:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@3c756e4d{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2017-09-13 16:27:33.885:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @581ms
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>

    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <distributable/>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>

    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <servlet-name>403Jsp</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/views/error/403.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>403Jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/403</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try accessing `http://localhost:8080/<someOtherPath>`?

Comment: @nullpointer : Yes, even the /denied page is not loading. I have added the webapplication as exploded option available in Intellij Idea.

Comment: Ideally [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) is a service response. So the url mapping is the first thing you would want to check.

Comment: @nullpointer : Can you elaborate on the URL mapping comment? Thanks.

Comment: share screenshot of your webapp folder contents

Comment: @Ravi : Nothing there, just README.txt. Do I have to manually add the WAR file there even if I am running it from IDE. Thanks.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain why the question was downvoted? Thanks. Apache tomcat has different way to operate than this one, that's why experiencing some issues.

Answer (score 0):

In `web.xml` below section defines which files to load as home page.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Now, you are saying, you don't have any file in application root folder EXCEPT `readme.txt`, then how would you expect anything to load ?

You need to make sure :

1. Your webapp is deployed correctly and has at least any of the file listed in `welcome-file-list`.
2. You need to access your `http://localhost:8080/<yourwebapp>`

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how to deploy with Jetty in Intellij. I have added the file in this manner : https://imgur.com/a/MkRU6   . Shouldn't the war be directly present in webapps when I start the server? Thanks

Comment: Already tried adding the JSP file in web.xml, no luck. I have also set the context-root to /, so I dont need to add the name of webapp.

Comment: @WeareBorg I haven't used Jetty server. So, I don't have much info. But, you can refer https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications

Comment: @WeareBorg you can't simply add jsp file and expect to run your application. You need to have application war file and deploy it to server root folder and then restart your server to reload your web application

Comment: Yes, Like you can see in the image, the war folder is marked for deployment when server starts.